# How to install awesomewm-git on ubuntu

Tags: linux, awesome-wm

I want to install awesomewm on ubuntu but there are a lot of dependencies for it. I have to search for each dependency on google and still can't find it. Is there a easy way to install the awesomewm (git version)?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [ubuntu.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: The offical awesomewm site said to ask on stackoverflow about anything regarding awesomewm. If this is not the right place to ask, why is there an awesomewm tag at all?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to `sudo apt install awesome awesome-extra` ? Awesome is in Ubuntu's repositories.

Otherwise if it really has to be the git version, just follow the instructions for Debian based distros (like Ubuntu) as it is described here on [Awesome's GitHub](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome)

The First of the following lines will install all the dependencies, that are needed for compiling awesome.

```
sudo apt build-dep awesome
git clone https://github.com/awesomewm/awesome
cd awesome
make package
sudo apt install *.deb
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried the first command --> `E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list`